# Square root decrement from user input

Tags: java, user-input, square-root, decrement

After getting an integer from the user and finding the square root, I need to find the square root of every number from i to 0. I am having trouble figuring out how to properly decrement the input so it prints out the square root of each number in an new line. I apologize if my title is not specific enough, I was having trouble attempting to describe this question.

```
public class Number {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i = 1;

    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");


    while (i >= 1)
    {

        i = scnr.nextInt();
        System.out.println(Math.sqrt(i));
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

decrement i within loop

```
int i = 0;
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
i = scnr.nextInt();
while (i >= 1)
{
    System.out.println(Math.sqrt(i));
    i--;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable using Java 8 streams then you will be able to do this in a more straightforward way without needing a traditional `for` loop:

```
IntStream.range(0, scanner.nextInt())
    .map(Math::sqrt).forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you are not familiar with streams, this statement can be interpreted as "create a stream of integers from 0 to the input number; map each of these integers to its own square root; print each number in the stream".

While the syntax looks a bit trickier it's worth getting used to using it.

Answer (score 0):

Get the user input **before** the loop, and decrement the variable, `i--`.

The *real* solution is to not just post code and expect it to work, but rather you should walk through your code mentally or on paper to think through its steps as they're occurring. Also study up on the Java operators, especially the `++` and `--` operators, and fully understand they're actions.

Comment: Thank you, I had the right code before but I seemed to have confused myself somewhere along the way.

Comment: @FilKuzmanovski: very confused to say the least. Why the `++` use?

Answer (score 0):

> You can use Function interface :::

```
int i = 0;
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
i = scnr.nextInt();
while (i >= 1)
{
    System.out.println(squareRoot(i));
    i--;
}

public Double squareRoot(Double number)
{
    Function<Double,Double> sqrtFunction = (Double x) -> Math.sqrt(x);
    double squareRoot = sqrtFunction.apply(number);

    System.out.println("Square root of"+number+"is:"+squareRoot);
    return squareRoot ;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Did you post this answer just to show a different way of achieving the desired result? From the `while` loop you call a method and that method calls a lambda. Kind of like going from New York to Los Angeles via Buenos Aires. By the way, the `while` loop can be shortened so as to contain a single line, i.e. `System.out.println(squareRoot(i--));` In any case, I think you should [edit] your question and, at least, post a link to the _javadoc_ of [interface] `Function`. You might also want to post a link that explains what a lambda expression is.

Comment: Yes @Abra, I just exploring Function interface provide customization on ready made function